# What does ** operator mean, C?

Tags: c, operators

What does the ** operator mean?
The "int *or" is just making sure it's gonna be a int pointer as the second argument but what does the "Item **w1" do?

for example;

```
typedef struct item{
 int data;
 struct item *next;
} Item;

void Inp(Item **w1, char c[], int *or) //writing numbers to a list
{
*or = scanf("%s" , c);
Conv(w1, c);
}
```

Comment: `Item **w1` is a pointer to a pointer to a `Item`. In other words, it is a double pointer, i.e, it points to the address of a pointer pointing to the address of `Item`.

Comment: "double pointer" is a *dangerous* expression (there is no `double` in sight). I prefer "pointer to pointer"

Answer (score 3):

Item **w1 is a pointer to a pointer to Item.